# How to override CActiveDataProvider Method to show CGridview in descending order by default in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, activerecord, yii

I have many models and gridviews in my project and every model has `create_dttm` field.

I would like now that how can I override class `CActiveDataProvider` where I'll add `DESC Sort condition`

i.e.

```
'sort' => array(
    'defaultOrder' => 'create_dttm DESC',
)
```

so that it'll work for all my gridviews instead of adding condition in each gridview.

Example:

```
public function search() {

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name', $this->name, true);
    $criteria->compare('age', $this->age);
    $criteria->compare('create_dttm', $this->create_dttm, true);
    $criteria->compare('update_dttm', $this->update_dttm, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 'create_dttm DESC',
        )
    ));
}
```

How can I deal with this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easy way is add the sort variable on each model.

or else you can using this method as below link, but if you using that's way you need change the name as well.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/173/an-easy-way-to-use-escopes-and-cactivedataprovider/

so my suggestion is, add the sort on each model.

Answer (score 2):

Have each model inherit from a BaseModel class, and overwrite the default scope method:

```
<?php
class BaseModel extends CActiveRecord {
...

    public function defaultScope() {
        return array(
            'order' => 'create_dttm DESC',
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can I add defaultScope() method in CActiveRecord instead of overriding basemodel class in every model.

Comment: Updating CActiveRecord  is not good practice because it is the part of framework. So, Samuel's ways of inheriting all the model classes with base model class and adding defaultScope() method like above will be good one .